# JAVASCRIPT - Change Element CSS on click

Tags: javascript, css

I have a navigation bar that when clicked, the page will be scrolled into that part of the page. I used this script.

```
$('li a').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
```

How do I change this element's style so that when it is clicked, it will slide into a certain part of the page as well as that navbar will have a different background image?
I tried adding an onclick() function in the links. It works but it does not scroll into the section of the page where it is suppose to slide. I tried adding the script inside the sliding script hoping it may have an effect but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this into that function.

```
$('li a').click(function(){
    var el = $(this);

    $('li a').removeClass('selected');
    el.addClass('selected');

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( el.attr('href') ).offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
```

Remove the "selected" class from any li then add it to the currently clicked one.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the $(element).css(cssElement, value) to change the CSS.

Example:

```
$("#myDiv").click(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "Black");
});
```